# PGP key decryption Error with openpgp - TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null at SecretKey.decrypt

Tags: javascript, encryption, pgp, openpgp.js

I am trying to decrypt one PGP file with [OpenPGP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp) javascript library. I am getting one error on the private key decryption

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null at SecretKey.decrypt
```

Here is my code snippet

```
    let privateKey = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(this.pgpConfig.privateKey));
    if (!privateKey.keys[0]) {
        throw privateKey.err[0];
    } else {
        privateKey = privateKey.keys[0];
    }
    await privateKey.decrypt(this.pgpConfig.passphrase);
```

Getting error from `await privateKey.decrypt(this.pgpConfig.passphrase);` line.

I tried to decrypt a file with another online tool and it seems to work fine over there.
So any idea what could be the issue here.

FYI I have generated keys from Kleopatra software.

Comment: Have you checked the key data (format, consistency)? After all, the snippet doesn't do much except read and decrypt the private key. The _data_ decryption itself happens later, see [here](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/tree/v4.10.10#streaming-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-data-with-pgp-keys). You should share some **test** key (incl. passphrase) with which the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Found the issue. Actually, the private key was not encrypted that's why it's throwing an error on the private key decryption step. Once remove this step it's working fine.